# Multi-line cell parsing with Python pandas with "\t" delimited flat file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a tab-delimited file that looks like this

```
H1    H2    H3
text1    text2with    text3
        runover
text1b    text2b    text3b
```

I'm using pandas.read_table to successfully parse each row, but I can't come up with a solution to concatenate the runover text backup into it's appropriate data row.

Comment: I'm sorry but i think that is not possible with standard Pandas imports. Only way to do it would by using the standard python read_line and checking the amount of tabs in each line, and then seeing if you have to continue on the next line.
Proper delimited files should have a double quote around the field with the \n (or \t for that matter).

Comment: You're right, Carst. FYI, This is from an multi-value "Pick" system form the early 90's